# Trying to get Retrofit onResponse executed first

Tags: java, android, retrofit, synchronous

My list in my activity called `AllStores` contains only null. I need this list, because I want to populate my ListView later on. The problem is caused because my callback is getting executed as last.

To clarify I have made a screenshot below:

Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFDHN.png

The screenshot also tells what I actually want. To achieve that I had tried it with a `AsyncTask`. However it didn't worked out as you can see in the screenshot.

Here is the code:

---

**EDIT 2.0 I have changed my `getSubprise()` method to become synchronous and using AsyncTask**

AllStores.java:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Response<List<Store>> subprises = new StoreService().getSubprises();
    System.out.println("AllStores (Activity) - subprise " + subprises);
}
```

StoreService.java:

```
       public Response<List<Store>> getSubprises() {
        new LongOperation().execute("");
        System.out.println("getStores (StoreService.java) value "+ getStores());
        return getStores();
    }

    private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Response<List<Store>>> {

        @Override
        protected Response<List<Store>> doInBackground(String... params) {
            System.out.println("doInBackground executed second");
            try {
                Call<List<Store>> call = subpriseAPI.listStores();
                stores=call.execute();
                Iterator it=stores.body().iterator();
//                while(it.hasNext())
//                    System.out.println(((Store)it.next()).getSTREET());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return stores;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //Can't put the call here because this is the main thread
            System.out.println("onPreExecute first");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Response<List<Store>> result) {
            //Can't put the call here because this is the main thread
            setStores(stores);
        }
    }

    public Response<List<Store>> getStores() {
        return stores;
    }

    public void setStores(Response<List<Store>> stores) {
        this.stores = stores;
    }
```

However I'm now still getting the same result see the screenshot below:

link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LI52q.png

The screenshot looks the same as the screenshot from above.

Comment: You should really read some docs about asynchronous code and callbacks . The complete asynctask is useless , due the enqueue call which is asynchronous. Your loaded data will be available when onresponse is called, so there is the point to update the ui.

Comment: @Andre Classen Yes what you said is indeed true. But I have edited my question, could you maybe answer it now :)?

Comment: Now you have changed the enqueue call, which was asynchronous, to the synchronous execeute call. The exception says it all 'NetworkOnMainThreadException'. A network call must be done in a background thread. E.g. the 'doInBackground()' call in a asyncTask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the result from the background thread to the main thread I had to use [AsyncTask.get()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#get()). By using that I could see a value in my `stores` variable instead of having a null value.

Below you can see my code for those who want to see it:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
public Response<List<Store>> getSubprises() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    LongOperation longOperation = new LongOperation();
    longOperation.execute("");
    stores = longOperation.get();
    return stores;
}

private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Response<List<Store>>> {
    @Override
    protected Response<List<Store>> doInBackground(String... params) {
        //System.out.println("doInBackground executed second");
        try {
            Call<List<Store>> call = subpriseAPI.listStores();
            stores=call.execute();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stores;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        //Can't put the call here because this is the main thread
        //System.out.println("onPreExecute first");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Response<List<Store>> result) {
        //Can't put the call here because this is the main thread
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you'd be better off letting Retrofit invoke the calls internally on its internal HTTP executor. this would involve changing your API interface to something like this:

```
public interface SubpriseAPI {
    @GET("api/locations/get")
    List<Store> listStores();
}
```

... and including any relevant configuration for Retrofit to handle the deserialization into your `Store` type.

however, if you want to invoke the calls yourself, you might consider hosting your own executor instance (or however you want to run your worker threads), something like this (not this exact implementation, but you should get the idea):

```
class StoreService {
...
private final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
...
public Response<List<Store>> getSubprises() {
  executorService.submit(new Callable<List<Store>>() {
            @Override
            public List<Store> call() throws Exception {
                final Call<List<Store>> call = subpriseAPI.listStores();

                try {
                    if(stores == null) {
                        stores = new ArrayList<>();
                    } else {
                        stores.clear();
                    }

                    stores.addAll(call.execute());

                    System.out.println("stores "+ stores);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).get();
...
```

**UPDATE**

i didn't realize you were (apparently) using Retrofit 2. i've had a chance to experiment a bit and this is what i came up with.

here are the relevant dependencies i have in my app/build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta2'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta2'
```

...here is my API interface:

```
public interface Api {
    @Headers("Accept: application/json")
    @GET("/v2/567595ad0f0000ea23315d02")
    public Call<List<Widget>> widgets();

}
```

...here is a simple DTO i'll be unmarshalling some JSON into:

```
public class Widget {
    public String value;
}
```

...and finally, here is my test activity:
public class Retrofit2TestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Api mockyApi = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://www.mocky.io")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()
            .create(Api.class);

        mockyApi.widgets().enqueue(new Callback<List<Widget>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<List<Widget>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                if(response.isSuccess()) {
                    Log.d(Retrofit2TestActivity.class.getName(), "## widgets.size() == " + response.body().size());
                } else {
                    Log.d(Retrofit2TestActivity.class.getName(), String.format("## response was NOT successful [%d]", response.code()));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                Log.d(Retrofit2TestActivity.class.getName(), String.format("## response was NOT successful [%s]", t.getMessage()));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

obviously you should substitute my `Widget` for your `Store` type. beyond that, manipulating the `List<Store>` as a normal member variable of your activity should be straightforward.

i hope that helped.

Comment: I will try this after I have slept. It's 3 o'clock in the night in my country hehe.

Comment: @hsi If I use `List<Store> listStores();` in SubpriseAPI.java then I'm getting the following error: `Unable to create call adapter for java.util.List<model.Store>`