# Android - Global variable is null after a method set its value

Tags: android

I've been trying to solve this problem but it is very persistence. I'm developing a SIP client with native android SIP stack, I used two device to run it from. The first device is android 5.0.2 and the second one is android 4.3 IIRC. The newer version run the app very fine but when I try to run the with the older version, the register method always fails, which said that the variable that I used is null, but it's not possible since the first thing that the register process is create that variable to be used. Here is the functions that I used:

```
public void createProfile(String id, String pas, String ip){
    try {
        SipProfile.Builder build = new SipProfile.Builder(id, ip);
        build.setPassword(pas);
        profile = build.build();
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("UNABLE TO CREATE PROFILE");
    }
}

public void openProfile(Context context){
    Intent i = new Intent();
    i.setAction("com.ta.SipTes.INCOMING_CALL");
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
    try {
        manager.open(profile, pi, reglist);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("UNABLE TO OPEN PROFILE");
    }
}

 public void registerProfile(){
    try{
        manager.register(profile, 30, reglist);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("UNABLE TO REGISTER PROFILE");
    }
}
```

And this is the method that I used to call them

```
 public void register(String id, String pas, String dom){
    createProfile(id, pas, dom);
    openProfile(MainPage.this);
    registerProfile();
}
```

And I used that method in onPostExecute, which looks like this:

```
public void onPostExecute(String stream){
        if (stream != null){
            id = tes;
            String pwd = "0";
            String adr = "192.168.5.5";
            register(id, pwd, adr);
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is the error log that I got:

```
    01-25 19:32:51.194 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-25 19:32:51.194 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at com.ta.SipTes.MainPage.openProfile(MainPage.java:160)
01-25 19:32:51.194 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at com.ta.SipTes.MainPage.register(MainPage.java:291)
01-25 19:32:51.194 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at com.ta.SipTes.MainPage$Process.doInBackground(MainPage.java:377)
01-25 19:32:51.194 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at com.ta.SipTes.MainPage$Process.doInBackground(MainPage.java:362)
01-25 19:32:51.194 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-25 19:32:51.194 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-25 19:32:51.195 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-25 19:32:51.195 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-25 19:32:51.195 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-25 19:32:51.195 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
01-25 19:32:51.195 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes I/System.out: UNABLE TO OPEN PROFILE
01-25 19:32:51.195 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-25 19:32:51.196 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at com.ta.SipTes.MainPage.registerProfile(MainPage.java:169)
01-25 19:32:51.196 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at com.ta.SipTes.MainPage.register(MainPage.java:292)
01-25 19:32:51.196 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at com.ta.SipTes.MainPage$Process.doInBackground(MainPage.java:377)
01-25 19:32:51.196 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at com.ta.SipTes.MainPage$Process.doInBackground(MainPage.java:362)
01-25 19:32:51.196 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
01-25 19:32:51.197 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
01-25 19:32:51.197 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
01-25 19:32:51.197 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
01-25 19:32:51.197 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
01-25 19:32:51.197 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
01-25 19:32:51.197 25768-25789/com.ta.SipTes I/System.out: UNABLE TO REGISTER PROFILE
```

Any idea why this is happening? Also does the older device being rooted could have something to do with it?

Thank you for the responses

Comment: I  can't see a class which extends the `AsyncTask`. After you have done that. You should create an object of the class that extends the `AsyncTask` class. Then you have to execute your background thread by calling the `execute()` method. After that you can get values from the background thread by calling the `get()` method. Here is a link of my question where I had solved it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34346224/trying-to-get-retrofit-onresponse-executed-first

Comment: @superkytoz sorry I didn't put it in my question since I have no problem with it,there is a class that extends `AsyncTask` class, and I execute it on onCreate(). The strange thing is in my android 5.03, all of the function works perfectly, but in the android 4.3, the register function won't work, it only got to create the profile, but the profile can't be used by open and register function, I did set the profile like this public SipProfile profile, and like my question above, I did set the value of profile in the create function, but both open and register function said that profile is null

Comment: So I tried running my app with the emulator, the emulator also produce null pointer, why did this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I feel really really stupid, turns out that my 4.0.3 device doesn't have native SIP stack and can't even do VoIP call with the native SIP stack, it still can do VoIP call if your app have it owns SIP stack.

After searching for awhile I found that `SipManager` can use `isApiSupported` and `isVoipSupported`to check whether the device could use the native SIP stack. And both the emulator and android 4.0.3 device returned both false for the check, hence that's why I keep getting null pointer, since the device don't have the native SIP stack to use.

Hopefully, this could be a lesson/advice for someone, thanks for the responses